# How to parse a fix log with no line separation delimiters

Tags: awk, sed, logs

Could somebody help with a solution to parse data in a fix log with no space line delimiters? The contents of the file are contained in a file called e.

```
8=FIX.4.49=025535=R49=UAT_RFQ56=UAT34=283052=20221101-20:16:01.304115=CPP131=booboo=155=EUR/USD167=FOR38=10000000015=EUR63=SP1=CPPIAGT453=1448=yogi447=D452=378=179=NT6R80=100000000467=07152=110=061
```

+++

The only common pattern that I would think possible is the '=' sign. So Ideally, if an '=' sign is encountered, take the value before the equal sign 2 or 3 positions and place on newline.

Ideally the output would look like the below:

```
8=FIX.4.4
9=0255
35=R
49=UAT_RFQ
56=UAT
34=2833
52=20221101-20:16:42.239
115=CPP
131=booboo
146=1
55=EUR/USD
167=FOR
38=100000000
15=EUR
63=SP
1=CPPIAGT
453=1
448=yogi
447=D
452=3
78=1
79=NT6R
80=100000000
467=07
152=
110=073
```

But I would be happy if could be separated just by a space.

```
8=FIX.4.4 9=0255 35=R 49=UAT_RFQ 56=UAT 34=2830 52=20221101-20:16:01.304 115=CPP 131=booboo=1 55=EUR/USD 167=FOR 38=100000000 15=EUR 63=SP 1=CPPIAGT 453=1 448=yogi 447=D 452=3 78=1 79=NT6R 80=100000000 467=07 152= 110=061
```

I've tried something as simple as: cat e | sed 's/=/\t/g'. Which results in

```
8       FIX.4.49        025535  R49     UAT_RFQ56       UAT34   283052  20221101-20:16:01.304115        CPP131  booboo  155     EUR/USD167      FOR38   10000000015     EUR63   SP1     CPPIAGT453      1448    yogi447 D452    378     179       NT6R80  100000000467    07152   110     061
```

Which doesn't represent the solution I'm looking for. If you could point me in the right direction or offer some advice.

Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `8=FIX.4.49=025535=R4` ... that could be `8=FIX.4.~49=02~5535=R4` or `8=FIX.4.4~9=02553~5=R4` etc. etc. .... how would you know which to choose?

Comment: How did you come to the solution you're looking for? I see no indication that there's any context here to know how to decode this data. Most likely you're missing something (null symbol?) in the data file, or the data file is unrecoverable.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do "one or two". Only either one, or two characters:

```
sed -e 's|\(.\)=|\n\1=|g' <e
sed -e 's|\(..\)=|\n\1=|g' <e
```

If you manage to find a pattern to decide from the text, how long the key is - then we can revisit this puzzle. But for now...

Are you absolutely sure there is no separator between key=value pairs?
Try looking at the file with a `hexdump` - it can help noticing an unprintable characters.

Comment: Hi White Owl - Thanks for your rapid response. The example that I've provided was from the client. Running a hexdump -f e, gives me nothing but garbage and bad format :( - We'll I figured I'd give it a try by asking the question. Much appreciated...

Comment: `hexdump -bc e`.

Comment: And do not forget about `man hexdump` :)

Comment: Cheers White Owl!!